# Set a hidden property to a ListBox Item - C#

Tags: c#, listbox

hey,
Does anybody knows a way to set a hidden value to a ListBox Item. 
As an alternative i can use another listbox simultaneously.
Thanks.

Comment: You can just set an arbitrary property on the listitem and retrieve it in the codebehind.  <asp:ListBox ... > <asp:ListItem ... myId="5" /> </asp:ListBoc>

Comment: What hidden value are you talking about? Can you provide any more details?

Comment: Not a hidden-feature.  Btw, asp.net, winforms or wpf?  It matters.  Winforms and wpf have a Tag, which is a property that can hold an arbitrary object.  Also, when you learn more you end up not needing these bad design crutches.

Comment: @ Cody Gray:I print some values from DataTable.so when I select one item, I want to get it's  let say Id number.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably looking for the Tag property. It holds an object type, which means you can save a reference to anything in there.

Although before setting on using the tag property, take a look at ItemsSource. Basically you can tie a collection of things to be the provider for your listbox, it's usually a superior alternative to dealing with Listbox items individually.